# How to change the order of thread execution ,that the last created thread run the first?

Tags: java, multithreading

We dynamically add threads.At the first the number is 1,and start running,as soon as 2_nd thread is created the first thread should block and 2_nd thread should execute and when 2_nd thread complete it task 1_st thread continue execution.this should work for dynamic N number of threads.I need sequently working threads and single thread  execution.
onItemClick everly time I create thread and need the last created thread execute other wait.Here is code inside onItemClick
while in my code it works sequently .one finishes then starts another one

```
Thread testThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

             Log.i("log", "name = " + i +                      Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, "ThreadName=" + magazineId);



    try {
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() != currentThread) {
            // Current Thread is Main Thread.
           currentThread.join(100);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    testThread.start();
```

Comment: read synchronization here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm

Comment: I have read it but it doesn't help how to  organize the described by me order of  thread execution.

Comment: first try out something,put up your code here and then community can certainly plug-in the missing pieces

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700871/what-is-difference-between-sleep-method-and-yield-method-of-multi-threading

Comment: I have post a piece of my code  Vihar

Comment: As soon as you find yourself trying to manipulate the execution order of threads, you know that your are definitely using the wrong tool for your job. If you need sequential execution, don’t use threads. The sole purpose of threads is non-sequential execution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link posted by Naman Gala, I think what you are looking for is join().

From the post:

> join() If any executing thread t1 calls join() on t2 i.e; t2.join()
>   immediately t1 will enter into waiting state until t2 completes its
>   execution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any API which does what you describe. If I understand correctly, you want the "newest" thread to preempt the execution of other (previous/older) threads, but this is not how the parallel execution model of Java works inherently.

So, to achieve what you want, you would need to add this kind of synchonization yourself explicitly.

That means: you need a separate data structure known to all threads (e.g. a sorted set of thread-timestamp pairs sorted by timestamp). In each thread you need to do a regular check if the (currently running) thread is the "topmost" in the sorted set (i.e., it has the right to be executed). If not, then it needs to wait.

You could use an additional semaphore with a 1-count (in other words a mutex) so you can make sure that only one thread is actually doing something at any given point in time.

Comment: and when the last thread complete its task ,other threads could continue.

Comment: could you provide me any useful link?